# XML elements source contains spaces

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new in reading XML content and now i'm running into the issue that some XML elements are containing a white space and VB.net is not accepting this.

Please have a look at the line of code starting with "Today_CurrentTemp". In this line you find an element , the space and quotes are not accepted like this by the XDocument.

Please help me how to work arround this. I cannot change the XML source format.

```
Const URL As String = "http://xml.buienradar.nl/"            
Try
            Dim xml = XDocument.Load(URL)


            Today_DescriptionShort = xml.<buienradarnl>.<weergegevens>.<verwachting_vandaag>.<samenvatting>.Value
            Today_DescriptionLong = xml.<buienradarnl>.<weergegevens>.<verwachting_vandaag>.<tekst>.Value
            Today_CurrentTemp = xml.<buienradarnl>.<weergegevens>.<actueel_weer>.<weerstations>.<weerstation id="6391">.<temperatuurGC>.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element `<weerstation id="6391">` does not contain whitespace in its *name*.
The whitespace indicates that the next literal is considered as an [Xml Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) with a specific value in double quotes (`id="6391"`).

Here is how you get the current temp:

```
Today_CurrentTemp = xml.<buienradarnl>.<weergegevens>.<actueel_weer>.<weerstations>.<weerstation>.Where(Function (x) x.Attribute("id") = "6391").First().<temperatuurGC>.Value
```

I used a lambda expression to give me the first occurance of an element named `<weerstation>` with an Attribute named `id` and value `6391`.

I assume that the `id` is unqiue so the `.First()` appraoch is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That works perfectly!

Now I have a similar issue with the line

```
<icoonactueel zin="bewolkt" ID="p">http://xml.buienradar.nl/icons/p.gif</icoonactueel>
<temperatuur10cm>11.3</temperatuur10cm>
```

Where bewolkt can have different values and the ID changes as wel, based on the type of weather. The only that I would like to have out of this element is the URL.

How to handle this?

see part of the XML below as example:

```
<weerstation id="6391">
<stationcode>6391</stationcode>
<stationnaam regio="Venlo">Meetstation Arcen</stationnaam>
<lat>51.30</lat>
<lon>6.12</lon>
<datum>04/13/2016 11:50:00</datum>
<luchtvochtigheid>83</luchtvochtigheid>
<temperatuurGC>10.5</temperatuurGC>
<windsnelheidMS>2.12</windsnelheidMS>
<windsnelheidBF>2</windsnelheidBF>
<windrichtingGR>123.0</windrichtingGR>
<windrichting>OZO</windrichting>
<luchtdruk>-</luchtdruk>
<zichtmeters>-</zichtmeters>
<windstotenMS>3.7</windstotenMS>
<regenMMPU>-</regenMMPU>
<icoonactueel zin="bewolkt" ID="p">http://xml.buienradar.nl/icons/p.gif</icoonactueel>
<temperatuur10cm>11.3</temperatuur10cm>
```

Comment: Do you just wand the URL no matter what attributes `zin` and `ID` are? or do you want it to be filtered to `bewolkt` and/or `p` only?

Comment: Btw... usually you should mark this question as answered (click on check mark next to my answer) and create a new one with your new question. SO likes to treat single Q&A-

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Const URL As String = "http://xml.buienradar.nl/"
Sub Main()
    Dim Today_DescriptionShort
    Dim Today_DescriptionLong
    Dim Today_CurrentTemp
    Try
        Dim xsrcdoc = XDocument.Load(URL)

        Today_DescriptionShort = (From xml In xsrcdoc.Descendants("verwachting_vandaag")
                                  Select New With {.Val = xml.Element("samenvatting").Value}).FirstOrDefault

        Today_DescriptionLong = (From xml In xsrcdoc.Descendants("verwachting_vandaag")
                                 Select New With {.Val = xml.Element("tekst").Value}).FirstOrDefault

        Today_CurrentTemp = (From xml In xsrcdoc.Descendants("weerstation").Where(Function(x) x.Attribute("id").Value = "6391")
                             Select New With {.Val = xml.Element("temperatuurGC").Value}).FirstOrDefault

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```